# Dynamic amount of navigation tabs with ListView in them

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

I want to be more efficient with my code, that's why I'm trying to simplify things (feel free to help me out in **KOTLIN**)

It's about a restaurant booking system where I have 2 big rooms, each room has a certain amount of tables (=hard coded number in my config). 
I'm trying to get one tab for each table where each tab contains a ListView which get's his information by a SQLite DB.

What I'm currently doing is, that I have 2 separated landing pages for each room, and for each table, I coded a Tab. This is certainly not the way to do it, but yeah, that's why I'm here asking for your help:

The Main Page does the fragment handling with a SectionsPageAdapter, as you can see I already implemented the "currentLocation" String containing "Room 1" or "Room 2".

```
  private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_one);

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
        final String currentLocation = extras.getString("currentLocation");


        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }



    private void setupViewPager (ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        if(currentLocation.equals(config.roomone) {
        // for loop?
        adapter.addFragment(new table_new_main(),"INFO");
        adapter.addFragment(new table_one(),"TABLE 1"); 
        adapter.addFragment(new table_two(),"TABLE 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new table_three(),"TABLE 3");
} else { ... }


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**Question 1**

The if loop does his thing, now how can I set a dynamic amount of Fragments based on the given number of Tables? With a for loop?

Now the fragments (this is the tricky part where I'm stuck):

public class table_one extends Fragment {

```
private ListView roomlist;
ListAdapter JSON_List;
ArrayList<String> Array_dates;
ArrayList<String> Array_table,Array_dayid,Array_location;
String currentLocation;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table, container, false);


    roomlist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_table);


    String id = config.ID_table3; // I hardcoded each table number, how can I pass that through my landing page to get it here?
    AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getContext(),
            AppDatabase.class, config.DB_TABLES).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    Array_dates = new ArrayList<String>();
    Array_table = new ArrayList<String>();
    Array_dayid = new ArrayList<String>();
    Array_location = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<value.size();i++) {
        Array_dates.add(value.get(i).getDaysDate());
        Array_table.add(value.get(i).getDaysPRX());
        Array_dayid.add(value.get(i).getDayid());
        Array_location.add(value.get(i).getLocation_id());
    }


    JSON_List = new RoomListAdapter(getContext(),id,Array_dates,null,null,Array_table,null,Array_dayid,Array_location,currentLocation);

    roomlist.setAdapter(JSON_List);
    return view;



}
```

**QUESTION 2**

So I need to pass to each fragment: the currentLocation (Room 1/2) and the table_id of itself, to know, where to get the data from my Database.
How can I do that?

Comment: you should consider using a recyclerview over a list view

Comment: Mh, do you think that helps me with this problem? I mean, how does this make the solution more accessible for me :)?

Comment: your question was a bit broad for me, so I just quickly looked over it to see what was going on and, in general, I advise people to swap from list view to recycler view, just because it's recommended by google for various reasons :) i'll see if I can give some general advice now on how to make this better for you

Comment: OK, updated my answer, give it a shot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by no means a comprehensive answer to your question, but you can definitely optimise this:

```
 private void setupViewPager (ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        if(currentLocation.equals(config.roomone) {
        // for loop?
        adapter.addFragment(new table_new_main(),"INFO");
        adapter.addFragment(new table_one(),"TABLE 1"); 
        adapter.addFragment(new table_two(),"TABLE 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new table_three(),"TABLE 3");
    } else { ... }


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

With an array of fragments, something along the lines of this:

```
    ArrayList<Fragment> listOfTables = new ArrayList<>();

    listOfTables.add(new example1()); 
    listOfTables.add(new example2()); 
    ...
```

so here, you can populate all your table fragments into one list ahead of time, then based on the config you have (your `if` statement)

you can cycle through your existing list of fragments and simply add them as you need them to the adapter:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < SomeValueHere; i++) { //you might even try reading this value from your config
        yourAdapter.add(listOfFragment.get(i));
    }
```

for your second question, you're saying you want to pass through some values to fragments.

Well, you can always try something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < SomeValueHere; i++) { //you should try reading this value from your config if can , perhaps
     Fragment table = listOfFragment.get(i);

     Bundle tableInfo = new Bundle();//add a bundle to the fragment with some extra details
     tableInfo.putInt("room_config", SomeIndicatorHereToShowWhichConfigIsChosen);
     tableInfo.putInt("table_id", i);

     table.setArguments(tableInfo);
        yourAdapter.add(table);
    }
```

Then, from your fragment, you can do something like this :

```
       @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getArguments();

    if (extras == null) {
   //maybe throw an exception, as this should never happen
    } else {
      Integer roomConfig = extras.getInt("room_config");
      Integer roomId = extras.getInt("room_id");
    }

}
```

Comment: any time @LosKayos, happy to help :D